# How to remove view in wpf

Tags: wpf, prism

How to remove view

there is no error now, however the following code can not remove view, no change in display

```
var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>()

foreach(var view in regionManager.Regions["Window1"].Views)
{
   if(regionManager.Regions["Window1"].Views.contains(this))
      regionManager.Regions["Window1"].Remove(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove it in a Foreach iterator. Use a for loop instead and loop through them backwards.

Comment: it can not regionManager.Regions["Window1"].Views[i], how to use for loop to get specified view

Comment: @viewer20q: In your updated code you do not even use the loop variable `view` any more, the code makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry I thought your code was just removing all the views in the region. If you are trying to do something else please describe it in more detail or update your code to demonstrate it.